# Why and when to use pointers in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion

I'm still very new to C, have only been learning for about a week at this point, but something I don't get is the use of pointers. I get how pointers work and I know how to use them, but I don't see why or when they should be used. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: How would you write a function to operate on any collection of data (be it list, array, whatever else) without pointers in C?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Use Pointers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423757/why-use-pointers-in-c)

Comment: There is also [Why use pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/162941/2505965), but many of the answers are problematic.

Comment: Yes, I understand the use of pointers a lot more now, sorry for asking such a newbie question, thank you all!

Comment: [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5727/995714), [Why use pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/162941/995714)

Comment: You would use pointers when you are in a situation where pointers are useful. When you are wondering how to solve something, and then you realize you can use a pointer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is enough to mention that arrays used in expressions with very rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

For example if you will write the expression

```
arr[i]
```

where `arr` is the array name then even in this expression the array is converted implicitly to a pointer to its first element.

Or another simple example: all C string functions deal with pointers of the type `char *` because passed arrays again are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

Think about how to write a general sort function for arrays of any types.